# Wave modifier Propagate Vertically

Tags: modifiers

I might just be trying the wrong tools for the job.
But im trying to get a wave modifier to propagate it's waves vertically without having to model at a 90 degree angle.(i like the assigned rotation as is)

I can get the desired motion by parenting it to an empty and moving that around.
However not along the desired axis.

Any ideas?

[image]

Undesired motion.

[image]

Desired motion after applying a 90 degree X rotation and rotating back. (having -90 degrees transformed.)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out myself.  In object mode you have to press ctrl + a and apply your rotation so the global rotation turns to zero.  Or just rotate your mesh in edit mode, and it will keep the same global co-ordinates.